# Alternative to Preferences in Java

Tags: java, preferences, java-web-start

I'm using the Java [Preferences API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html) to store and retrieve small pieces of information in a swing/java application.

Now i have setup Java Web start to launch the application from my web page, and I get a security exception. In order to get rid of this exception, I'd have to prompt the user for permissions. And I refuse to do that because my application does nothing else that would require the user's permission.

That's why I need an alternative solution for storing a few key values from one execution to another. Some sort of cookie or whatever. Do you know any please ?

Comment: it is quite unreasonable that app can't save moderate amount of client data on client machine. you probably have to sign your app.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You may want to look into using [`PersistenceService`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/javaws/developersguide/examples.html#PersistenceService), a feature of [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) that "provides methods for storing data locally on the client system, even for applications that are running in the restricted execution environment." Related examples may be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/examples.html) and [here](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#ps).

Comment: @Andrew Thompson, the author of the [example](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#ps), may be able to offer additional guidance.

Comment: It's exactly what I needed and the example you pointed is very clear. Thanks a lot.