# persistent configuration, JTable, JXTable

Tags: java, configuration, jtable, persistence, jxtable

I would like to store the state of my `JTable` (technically I'm using a `JXTable` if that helps) in some sort of configuration file. My goal is that when a user runs my spreadsheet program, its state (ie which columns are hidden, the column order) will persist between executions.

Are there any built in functions I could use for this? Or any suggestions on what would be a good place to start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use either of the approaches cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13309183/230513) to persist the  data in your `TableModel` and any desired display state.