# Ways to license a software on Mac (file based/ offline)

Tags: java, swing, dmg

I created a Java application for Mac, which I plan to distribute as a dmg file - users can simply mount the dmg and run the application. The problem I am facing is with the licensing.

As of now, I have written the code which does file based license. However, I failed to foresee that disk images cannot be written into and that the application cannot create and save the a text based license file in the current directory when the application is opened directly from the mounted dmg!

As a workaround, the only way I could figure out is to copy the application from the mounted dmg to a folder on my Mac, then run the application from there and enter the license details so that they can be saved in a license text file.

Can someone please suggest me a better approach to it as this one is unnecessarily cumbersome and burdening.

I don't want to do online validation of license everytime the user wants to run the application, so I am keen on exploring other ways to do offline validation for the software license which works out to be easier to use.

Your help is much appreciated

Comment: The first thought that comes to mind here is "Why not place the license in the Application Support folder?"

Is there some kind of constraint that requires the license to be saved within the current directory?

Comment: Thanks for the tip.. will try it out today.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [License3j](http://projects.verhas.com/com.verhas.licensor/license3j/license3j/) for this. I have used this to license my java application.

You could find a [Sample](http://projects.verhas.com/com.verhas.licensor/license3j/license3j/sample.html) here

Comment: Thanks.. will try it out today.

Answer (score 1):

You can write your license key in `java.util.Preferences`, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11724866/230513), or `javax.jnlp. PersistenceService`, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6886694/230513).