# Accessing platform-specific application data area

Tags: java, swing, storage

In Java, I need to find a way to store some data locally so that it is available between reboots. Simple things, such as window location/size. I know that such information is usually stored in `C:\Users\<username>\AppData` on Windows (accessed by typing `%APPDATA%` in the address bar of Windows Explorer), but I have no idea where it is stored on Mac OS X. (As a side note, I still don't understand the structure of that `%APPDATA%` folder on Windows, with its `\Roaming`, `\Local`, `\LocalLow`, etc. subfolders.)

Surely there is some way for information like window location to be stored in these areas depending on the OS. Perhaps there is even an library already pre-built for doing these relatively ubiquitous tasks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *In Java, I need to find a way to store some data locally so that it is available between reboots. Simple things, such as window
>   location/size.*

I think [Preferences API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/preferences/index.html) suits this requirement. In a nutshell:

> Applications require preference and configuration data to adapt to the
>   needs of different users and environments. The `java.util.prefs` package
>   provides a way for applications to store and retrieve user and system
>   preference and configuration data. The data is stored persistently in
>   an implementation-dependent backing store. There are two separate
>   trees of preference nodes, one for user preferences and one for system
>   preferences.

There is a short yet useful tutorial [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaPreferences/article.html). And here is a little example based on your requirements:

```
import java.util.prefs.Preferences;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class SwingPreferencesTest {

    private void createAndShowGUI() {

        JTextField dummyTextField = new JTextField(20);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Demo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(dummyTextField);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        Preferences prefs = Preferences.userRoot().node(this.getClass().getName());

        // Define default values here
        System.out.println("width: " + prefs.getDouble("width", 100d));
        System.out.println("height: " + prefs.getDouble("height", 100d));
        System.out.println("x: " + prefs.getDouble("x", 0d));
        System.out.println("y: " + prefs.getDouble("y", 0d));

        // Set new values here
        prefs.putDouble("width", frame.getPreferredSize().getWidth());
        prefs.putDouble("height", frame.getPreferredSize().getHeight());
        prefs.putDouble("x", frame.getLocationOnScreen().getX());
        prefs.putDouble("y", frame.getLocationOnScreen().getY());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new SwingPreferencesTest().createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

If you run it the first time you'll see the preferences default values in console:

```
width: 100.0
height: 100.0
x: 0.0
y: 0.0
```

If you run it again then these values are updated. In my case:

```
width: 240.0
height: 59.0
x: 130.0
y: 130.0
```

### Edit

As per @Puce comment below, on Windows data is stored in the registry and it makes sense because it's the way that Windows uses to store user/system/software data. You can find the registry entry generated in the example under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\JavaSoft\Prefs\[package\class name]` as shown in picture below:

[image]

***Note:*** tested on Windows 8 x64, JDK 1.7

If you don't want to fill the registry with these preferences, then you can just store a path to your application folder (as other applications do) and use this path to load config data from plain properties files. The main advantage to keep using Preferences (at least to store the application's path) is the mechanism to retrieve/store config data is designed to be cross-platform and JVM implementers (not developers) are who have to deal with the actual implementation.

Comment: Doesn't java.util.prefs store things in the Registery on Windows?

Comment: It's up to the implementation actually. Most likely yes, I think it does. OTOH it's a cross-platform way to store user custom config better than dealing with files/properties. As far as I understand it this API is designed to the main purpose asked in the question @Puce

Comment: `PersistenceService`, mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6886694/230513), is an alternative.

Comment: Thanks for that link, it's quite useful! However the link to Andrew Thompson's example seems no longer available @trashgod

Comment: Thanks, @dic19. Your answer was very clear and concise. It didn't explicitly detail how to set a JFrame size & location with that Preferences data, but I was able to figure it out on my own in about an hour. (I'm a slow learner.) Thank you again; you're awesome!

Answer (score 0):

You could store the data in

```
Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home")).resolve(".my-application-conf")
```

or something similar. That should work across OSes.

Comment: "user.home" won't get you AppData or one of its sub-directories, though.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no solution for this in the standard Java library.

You would either have to find a 3rd-party library, which does this, or use one of the alternative solutions (see other answers).