# How to store the recent items permanently using swing

Tags: java, swing, permanent, recent-file-list

I want to add recent opened files to recent menu.I did that task.But,it doesn't store permanently.That means when i close the running application,the recent items also removed.I want to store the recent items permanently,after re run the application the recent open items are available.

My Code:

```
public class RecentItems extends javax.swing.JFrame {
int i=0;
Queue<String> q;
JMenuItem item;
String recentPath;
int recentItems_count=0;
JTextPane textPane;
JScrollPane scrollPane;
public RecentItems() {
    initComponents();
    q=new LinkedList<>();
    textPane=new JTextPane();
    scrollPane=new JScrollPane(textPane);
}
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    tp = new javax.swing.JTabbedPane();
    jMenuBar1 = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
    jMenu1 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
    openAction = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    recentItems = new javax.swing.JMenu();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jMenu1.setText("File");

    openAction.setText("OPEN");
    openAction.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            openActionActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    jMenu1.add(openAction);

    recentItems.setText("Recent");
    jMenu1.add(recentItems);

    jMenuBar1.add(jMenu1);

    setJMenuBar(jMenuBar1);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(tp, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(tp, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 279, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void openActionActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    FileDialog fd = new FileDialog(RecentItems.this, "Select File", FileDialog.LOAD);
    fd.setVisible(true);
    String title;
    String sts;
    File file;
    if (fd.getFile() != null) {
        sts = fd.getDirectory() + fd.getFile();
        file=new File(sts);
        title=fd.getFile();
        JInternalFrame internalFrame = new JInternalFrame("",true,true); 
        i++;
        internalFrame.setName("Doc "+i);
        internalFrame.setTitle(title);
        try {
            internalFrame.setSelected(true);
        } 
        catch (PropertyVetoException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(RecentItems.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }      
        internalFrame.add(scrollPane);
        tp.add(internalFrame);
        try{
            tp.setSelectedIndex(i-1);  
        }
        catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException ioe){   
        }
        try {
            textPane.setPage(file.toURI().toURL());
        } 
        catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(RecentItems.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(RecentItems.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        setVisible(true);
        textPane.setCaretPosition(0);
        q.add(sts);
        recentItems_count++;              
        if(recentItems_count>1) {
            int size=q.size();
            String[] strArray = new String[q.size()];
            q.toArray(strArray);
            for(int k=0;k<size;k++) {
                for(int i=size-1;i>k;i--) {
                    if(strArray[k].equals(strArray[i])) {  
                        q.remove(strArray[k]); 
                        tp.remove(internalFrame);
                    }
                }
            }
        } 
        if(q.size()<=3) {
            recentItems.removeAll();
            for( String string : q) {  
                item=recentItems.add(string);
                recentPath=item.getText();
            }
        }
        else if(q.size()>3) {
            q.remove();
            recentItems.removeAll();
            for( String string : q)  {
                item=recentItems.add(string);
                recentPath=item.getText();
            }
        }
    }
}                                          

public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(RecentItems.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(RecentItems.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(RecentItems.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(RecentItems.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new RecentItems().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}                    
private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu1;
private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar1;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem openAction;
private javax.swing.JMenu recentItems;
private javax.swing.JTabbedPane tp;                
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [Java Preferences API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html) to store the user preferences in an easy and cross-platform way.

### Steps:

- Define the preferences Object:
  `Preferences prefs = Preferences.userNodeForPackage(yourpackagename.class);`
- Set the key name for the reference
  `final String PREF_NAME = "recent_items";`
- Put the value in the the preference
  `prefs.put(PREF_NAME, value);`
- Retrieve the value associated with the specified key in this preference node
  `String propertyValue = prefs.get(PREF_NAME, yourDefaultValue);`

### Code:

After adding it to your example:

```
package com.example;

public class Test extends javax.swing.JFrame  implements ActionListener {

    int i = 0;
    Queue<String> q;
    JMenuItem item;
    String recentPath;
    int recentItems_count = 0;
    JTextPane textPane;
    JScrollPane scrollPane;

    // Retrieve the user's preference node for this package
    Preferences prefs = Preferences.userNodeForPackage(com.example.Test.class);

    // key name of the preference
    final String PREF_NAME = "recent_items";
    private List<String> itemsAll = new ArrayList<String>();

    public Test() {
        initComponents();
        q = new LinkedList<>();
        textPane = new JTextPane();
        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textPane);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {

        tp = new javax.swing.JTabbedPane();
        jMenuBar1 = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
        jMenu1 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
        openAction = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        recentItems = new javax.swing.JMenu();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jMenu1.setText("File");

        openAction.setText("OPEN");
        openAction.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                openActionActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jMenu1.add(openAction);

        recentItems.setText("Recent");
        jMenu1.add(recentItems);

        loaditemsFromPreferences();
        for (String item : itemsAll) {
            JMenuItem newMenuItem = recentItems.add(item);
            newMenuItem.addActionListener(this);
        }

        jMenuBar1.add(jMenu1);

        setJMenuBar(jMenuBar1);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(
                getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(
                javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addComponent(tp,
                javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING,
                javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE));
        layout.setVerticalGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(
                javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addComponent(tp,
                javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING,
                javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 279, Short.MAX_VALUE));

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>

    private JInternalFrame loadFile(String sts, String title) {
        File file = new File(sts);
        JInternalFrame internalFrame = new JInternalFrame("", true, true);
        i++;
        internalFrame.setName("Doc " + i);
        internalFrame.setTitle(title);
        try {
            internalFrame.setSelected(true);
        } catch (PropertyVetoException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        internalFrame.add(scrollPane);
        tp.add(internalFrame);
        try {
            tp.setSelectedIndex(i - 1);
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ioe) {
        }
        try {
            textPane.setPage(file.toURI().toURL());
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        setVisible(true);
        textPane.setCaretPosition(0);
        q.add(sts);
        return internalFrame;
    }

    private void openActionActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        FileDialog fd = new FileDialog(Test.this, "Select File",
                FileDialog.LOAD);
        fd.setVisible(true);
        if (fd.getFile() != null) {
            String sts = fd.getDirectory() + fd.getFile();
            String title = fd.getFile();
            JInternalFrame internalFrame = loadFile(sts, title);
            recentItems_count++;
            if (recentItems_count > 1) {
                int size = q.size();
                String[] strArray = new String[q.size()];
                q.toArray(strArray);
                for (int k = 0; k < size; k++) {
                    for (int i = size - 1; i > k; i--) {
                        if (strArray[k].equals(strArray[i])) {
                            q.remove(strArray[k]);
                            tp.remove(internalFrame);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if (q.size() <= 3) {
                recentItems.removeAll();
                itemsAll.clear();
                for (String string : q) {
                    item = recentItems.add(string);
                    recentPath = item.getText();
                    itemsAll.add(recentPath);
                    storeToPreferences();
                }
            } else if (q.size() > 3) {
                q.remove();
                recentItems.removeAll();
                itemsAll.clear();
                for (String string : q) {
                    item = recentItems.add(string);
                    recentPath = item.getText();
                    itemsAll.add(recentPath);
                    storeToPreferences();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager
                    .getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(
                    java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(
                    java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(
                    java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(
                    java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Test().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    private void loaditemsFromPreferences() {
        for (int i = 0; i < maxItems; i++) {
            String value = prefs.get(PREF_NAME + i, "");
            if (!value.equals("")) {
                itemsAll.add(value);
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private void storeToPreferences() {
        for (int i = 0; i < maxItems; i++) {
            if (i < itemsAll.size()) {
                prefs.put(PREF_NAME + i, (String) itemsAll.get(i));
            } else {
                prefs.remove(PREF_NAME + i);
            }
        }
    }


    private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu1;
    private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar1;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem openAction;
    private javax.swing.JMenu recentItems;
    private javax.swing.JTabbedPane tp;
    private final int maxItems = 3;

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Selected: " + e.getActionCommand());
        loadFile(e.getActionCommand(), e.getActionCommand());
    }
}
```

### Related Documentation:

- [Preferences API Overview](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/preferences/overview.html)

### Alternative Solution:

- From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6886694/230513) by [trashgod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26753852/how-to-store-the-recent-items-permanently-using-swing/26755502?noredirect=1#comment42094071_26755502)

> You may want to look into using [`PersistenceService`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/javaws/developersguide/examples.html#PersistenceService), a feature of [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) that "provides methods for storing data locally on the client system, even for applications that are running in the restricted execution environment." Related examples may be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/examples.html) and [here](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#ps).

Comment: +1 for the example; also consider this [alternative](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6886694/230513).

Comment: Thank You.The Above Code Working Fine.But,It produces an Warning as "Nov 06, 2014 10:25:04 AM java.util.prefs.WindowsPreferences <init>
WARNING: Could not open/create prefs root node Software\JavaSoft\Prefs at root 0x80000002. Windows RegCreateKeyEx(...) returned error code 5.".How can I resolve the Warning.

Comment: @user3792689: I didn't get the warning, however it seems to be an [open issue](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21496098) in the Java tracker, [see here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/Google-Web-Toolkit/LQfsBSwD_ug/wJuRL3QD0W4J)

Comment: should we always call .flush on the end of the preference .putString() or .putBoolean() values ? @InfiniteRecursion

Answer (score 0):

Well, you should store recent files in database or properties.

[Here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Development-Class/Storerecentitemsegrecentfileinamenuorrecentsearchtextinasearchdialog.htm) is an example how to solve this using properties file.

Comment: Is it possible to call That class from my Application.If Yes,How can I call It.Please Check it once.I can not understand the some part of the in the Example.